# Ajax auto remove mouse selection

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on an Ajax function, the function must fetch users from a database every 3 seconds. It works fine. The real trouble is, per 3 seconds the function refresh so if anyone select (by mouse) the selection will be removed after 3 seconds.

What should I do to solve this?

Simple example:

```
ajax_load();

setInterval(function(){
   ajax_load();

}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. When user changes his selection, cache the selection to a safe place (ex: sessionStorage or a hidden input outside of the HTML part that got changed)
2. After the content gets re-rendered, restore the selections from where you cached.

Pseudocode:

```
var ajax_load = function(callback){
    $.ajax("request-url", {
      success: function(data) {
         appendHTMLContent();
         if(callback) callback();
      }
   });
};

ajax_load();

[change-event-example].change(function(){
    cacheUserSelection();
});

setInterval(function(){
   ajax_load(restoreUserSelectionCallBack);
}, 3000);
```

Example:

`[change-event-example]` means you need to catch the event of the changes from the user, then cache that changes. Ex, if changes occur in the checkboxes then it should be:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="user_selection" data-no="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="user_selection" data-no="2" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        cacheUserSelection($(this).data("no"));
    }       
});
```

Comment: i didn't get it could you explain  these: 


    `[change-event-example].change(function(){
      cacheUserSelection();
    });`

and
    ajax_load(restoreUserSelectionCallBack);